# pass statement as string in python

Tags: python

i've been writing python code to automatically login the forms.i've found this code in youtube..

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as c:
    url='https://www.facebook.com/'
    USER = 'testit.python'
    PASS = 'testing321'
    c.get(url)
    login_data = dict(email=USER,pass=PASS)
    c.post(url, data = login_data)
    page = c.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
    print (page.content)
```

but in "login_data = dict(email=USER,pass=PASS)" pass is the built-in statement. so it produces the error.is there any method to convert a pass statement to string?

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved by using a dictionary literal.

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as c:
    url='https://www.facebook.com/'
    USER = 'testit.python'
    PASS = 'testing321'
    c.get(url)
    login_data = {"email":USER,"pass":PASS}
    c.post(url, data = login_data)
    page = c.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
    print (page.content)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't. "pass" is a python keyword and as such it's not a valid identifier,but you can pass it as string as,

```
login_data = {'email': USER,'pass':PASS}
```